# Remove Case Class Definition in asJson output from Circe

Tags: json, scala, traits, case-class, circe

Consider:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.syntax._
sealed trait Data
case class Failed(foo: String, bar: String) extends Data
case class Success(foo1:String, bar1:String) extends Data
case class Task(Foo:String, Data: Data)

val something = Task("test", Failed("1", "2"))
println(something.asJson)
```

This outputs:

```
val something: Task = Task(test,Failed(1,2))
{"Foo" : "test", "Data" : {"Failed" : {"foo" : "1","bar" : "2"}}}
```

But what I really want, is it to output:

```
{"Foo" : "test", "Data" : {"foo" : "1", "bar" : "2"}}
```

Effectively, I just want to delete the "Failed" block but keep everything within that block.

Build info:

```
val scalaVer = "2.13.8"

lazy val circeJsonSchemaVersion = "0.2.0"
lazy val circeVersion = "0.14.3"
lazy val circeOpticsVersion = "0.14.1"

"io.circe" %% "circe-json-schema" % circeJsonSchemaVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-core" % circeVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % circeVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % circeVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-literal" % circeVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-generic-extras" % circeVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-optics" % circeOpticsVersion,
```

I have tried using @JsonCodec but wasn't able to get it working. I looked at custom codecs but that seems like it could be a giant rabbit hole.

EDIT: Fixed bad copy/paste in output

Comment: https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html#a-more-generic-solution `sealed trait Event` `case class Foo(i: Int) extends Event` `(Foo(100): Event).asJson.noSpaces` `// res3: String = "{\"i\":100}"`

Comment: Didn't understand about rabbit holes.

Comment: Probably you missed a `{` in `{"Foo" : "test", "Data" : "foo" : "1","bar" : "2"}}`

Comment: Yeah the missing "{" was a mistake and I fixed it in the question.

Comment: Scratch that, I think I may understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A more generic solution](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html#a-more-generic-solution) recommends

```scala
import GenericDerivation.{ decodeEvent => _, encodeEvent => _ }

object ShapesDerivation {
  import io.circe.shapes // "io.circe" %% "circe-shapes" % ...
  import shapeless.{ Coproduct, Generic }

  implicit def encodeAdtNoDiscr[A, Repr <: Coproduct](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, Repr],
    encodeRepr: Encoder[Repr]
  ): Encoder[A] = encodeRepr.contramap(gen.to)

  //...
}
```

but this seems to be outdated.

You can try to derive encoders for non-labelled coproducts manually yourself (i.e. coproducts of the form `Failed :+: Success :+: CNil` rather than `FieldType[Symbol @@ "Failed", Failed] :+: FieldType[Symbol @@ "Success", Success] :+: CNil`)

```scala
import io.circe.Encoder
import shapeless.{:+:, CNil, Coproduct, Generic, Inl, Inr}

trait NoLabelCoproductEncoders {
  implicit def noLabelEnc[A, Repr <: Coproduct](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, Repr],
    enc: NoLabelCoproductEncoder[Repr]
  ): Encoder[A] = enc.contramap(gen.to)
}

trait NoLabelCoproductEncoder[A <: Coproduct] extends Encoder[A]
object NoLabelCoproductEncoder {
  implicit def ccons[H, T <: Coproduct](implicit
    hEnc: Encoder[H],
    tEnc: NoLabelCoproductEncoder[T]
  ): NoLabelCoproductEncoder[H :+: T] = {
    case Inl(h) => hEnc(h)
    case Inr(t) => tEnc(t)
  }

  implicit val cnil: NoLabelCoproductEncoder[CNil] = _.impossible
}
```

This works with `semiauto`

```scala
import io.circe.generic.semiauto

sealed trait Data
object Data extends NoLabelCoproductEncoders

case class Failed(foo: String, bar: String) extends Data
object Failed {
  implicit val failedEnc: Encoder[Failed] = semiauto.deriveEncoder[Failed]
}
case class Success(foo1:String, bar1:String) extends Data
object Success {
  implicit val successEnc: Encoder[Success] = semiauto.deriveEncoder[Success]
}

case class Task(Foo:String, Data: Data)
object Task {
  implicit def taskEnc: Encoder[Task] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
}

import io.circe.syntax._

val something = Task("test", Failed("1", "2"))
something.asJson.noSpaces
// {"Foo":"test","Data":{"foo":"1","bar":"2"}}
```

and with `auto`

```scala
sealed trait Data
object Data extends NoLabelCoproductEncoders

case class Failed(foo: String, bar: String) extends Data
case class Success(foo1:String, bar1:String) extends Data

case class Task(Foo:String, Data: Data)

import io.circe.generic.auto._
import Data._ // to make noLabelEnc of higher priority for Data, otherwise it's ambiguous with Circe auto._ encoders (in LowPriorityEncoders)
import io.circe.syntax._

val something = Task("test", Failed("1", "2"))
something.asJson.noSpaces
// {"Foo":"test","Data":{"foo":"1","bar":"2"}}
```